# Ripple kind animation when app theme is changing Android

Tags: java, android

I want to add the same theme changing animation

[image]
(This is Telegram app)

I have a `radioGroup`
[image]
where `onChangeListener` changes themes
I want to achive this:
when you check Dark radio, the animation will start from the position of dark radio
if you check light, it will start from light and etc
How is it possible to make such kind of animation in andoid app?
my full theme chaning code:

```
public void chooseTheme(MenuItem item) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        final View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_theme,null);
        Button btn_cancel = mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        Button btn_okay = mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_okay);
        alert.setView(mView);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        final RadioGroup themeGroup = mView.findViewById(R.id.themeGroup);

        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        themeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup themeGroup, int i) {
                switch(i) {
                    case R.id.radioLight:
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Light mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        restartApp();
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioDark:
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                        setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Dark mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        restartApp();
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioSystem:
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"System mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        restartApp();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        btn_okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    public void restartApp() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Check this github project: https://github.com/danieleorlando/CircularReveal

Comment: interesting, i'll see it, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check my github library: https://github.com/imandolatkia/Android-Animated-Theme-Manager

in this library you can create your custom themes and change them dynamically with ripple animation, **like your question image**.

[image]

Comment: The repo you linked appears to be your own: if this is the case, then you need to *explicitly* disclose that fact. Otherwise, your post may be considered spam.